# How to handle crash from notification service extension crash?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, apple-push-notifications, unnotificationserviceextension

Getting weird from notification service extension
I think this might be due to sending of AWS event from receivedNotification method which might be taking more time that causes OS killing it. if this the scenario then how should i handle the crash and prevent it.
please check the crash logs,

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace ASSERTIOND, Code 0xdead10cc
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001c829bed0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001c829b3a8 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c869fbc4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 236
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c869aa60 __CFRunLoopRun + 1396
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c869a1cc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5   Foundation                      0x00000001c908f404 -[NSRunLoop+ 33796 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 300
6   Foundation                      0x00000001c90cadf4 -[NSRunLoop+ 278004 (NSRunLoop) run] + 88
7   libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001c836c070 _xpc_objc_main + 516
8   libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001c836ea30 xpc_main + 180
9   Foundation                      0x00000001c90ccdb0 +[NSXPCListener serviceListener] + 0
10  PlugInKit                       0x00000001ce2eb498 0x1ce2d8000 + 79000
11  PlugInKit                       0x00000001ce2eb2c4 0x1ce2d8000 + 78532
12  PlugInKit                       0x00000001ce2eb848 0x1ce2d8000 + 79944
13  Foundation                      0x00000001c92b46bc NSExtensionMain + 64
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001c815abb4 start + 4
```

Answer (score 1):

> @Sumeet.Jain  you need to set debug executable on your extension
>   project  their are some steps here.

**step 1: select your service extension project to run

step 2: you will see list of your project below some option "SELECT EDIT SCHEME" option**

**step 3: after then you have to go for  RUN -> INFO -> EXECUTABLE

step 4: and you should change "ASK TO LAUNCH" to "YOUR PROJECT"**

> THATS IT.

Comment: crashes are happening in production, how to prevent this crashes in next release that i need to know. Above steps are for debugging purpose right ?

Comment: @Sumeet.Jain Yes, it for debugging purpose

Comment: i have debugged the issue, and it might be due to sending events from service extension method which is taking more time and getting killed by OS. What i want is **how to prevent the crash when OS kills the service**.

Comment: @Sumeet.Jain i have get your view. keep a chill i will update you shortly.